I keep getting an error of 'dataIndex is not assignable' to
i am really new to this,and everything looks good on my code, but i keep getting this error of
Type '{ dataIndex: string; title: string; defaultFilteredValue: any; filterIcon: Element; filterDropdown: (props: FilterDropdownProps) => Element; render: (value: any, record: Company) => Element; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ColumnProps<Company>'.
  Property 'dataIndex' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ColumnProps<Company>'.ts(2322).

Below is the code block for my list.tsx file.
import CustomAvatar from '@/components/custom-avatar';
import { Text } from '@/components/text';
import { COMPANIES_LIST_QUERY } from '@/graphql/queries';
import { Company } from '@/graphql/schema.types';
import { CompaniesListQuery } from '@/graphql/types';
import { currencyNumber } from '@/utilities';
import { SearchOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';
import { CreateButton, DeleteButton, EditButton, FilterDropdown,
   List, useTable } from '@refinedev/antd';
   import { HttpError, getDefaultFilter, useGo } from '@refinedev/core';
import { GetFieldsFromList } from '@refinedev/nestjs-query';
import { Input, Space, Table } from 'antd';



export const CompanyList = ({children}: React.PropsWithChildren) => {
  const go = useGo();
  const {tableProps, filters } = useTable< 
  GetFieldsFromList< CompaniesListQuery>,
  HttpError,
  GetFieldsFromList<CompaniesListQuery>
  > ({
    resource: 'companies',
    onSearch: (values) => {
      return [
        {
          field: 'name',
          operator: 'contains',
          value: values.name
        }
      ]
    },
    pagination:{
      pageSize: 12,
    },
    sorters: {
      initial: [
        {
          field: 'createdAt',  
          order: 'desc'
        }
      ]
    },
    
    filters: {
      initial: [
        {
          field: 'name',
          operator: 'contains',
          value: undefined
        }
      ]
    },
    meta: {
      gqlQuery: COMPANIES_LIST_QUERY
    }
  })
  return (
    <div>
    <List
    breadcrumb={false}
    headerButtons={() => (
      <CreateButton 
      onClick={() => {
        go({
          to: {
            resource:'companies',
            action: 'create'
          },
          options: {
            keepQuery: true
          },
          type: 'replace'
        })
      }}/>
    )}
    >
      <Table
      {...tableProps}
      pagination={{
        ...tableProps.pagination,
      }}
      >
        <Table.Column<Company> 
        dataIndex="name"
        title="Company Title"
        defaultFilteredValue={ getDefaultFilter('id', filters)}
        filterIcon={<SearchOutlined />}
        filterDropdown={(props) => (
          <FilterDropdown{...props}>
          <Input placeholder= "Search Company" />
          </FilterDropdown>
        )}
        render={(value, record) => (
        <Space>
          <CustomAvatar shape="square" 
          name={record.name} src={record.avatarUrl} />
          <Text style={{ whiteSpace: 'nowrap'}}>
            {record.name}
          </Text>
        </Space>
      )} 
      /> 
      <Table.Column<Company>
        dataIndex ="totalRevenue"
        title="Open deals amount"
        render={(value, company) => (
          <Text>
            {currencyNumber(company?.dealsAggregate?.[0].sum?.value || 0)}
          </Text>
        )}
          
        />
        <Table.Column<Company>
        dataIndex="id"
        title="Actions"
        fixed="right"
        render={(value) =>(
         <Space>
          <EditButton hideText size="small" recordItemId={value}/>
          <DeleteButton hideText size="small" recordItemId={value}/>
         </Space>
        )}     
      />
      </Table>
    </List>
    {children}
    </div>
  )
}



i tried checking tracing "dataIndex" and it exists in this other file, and all looks goood, but i really do not know what i can do to fix this. The a section of the root file is below (named interface.tsx):
export type AlignType = 'start' | 'end' | 'left' | 'right' | 'center' | 'justify' | 'match-parent';
export interface ColumnType<RecordType> extends ColumnSharedType<RecordType> {
    colSpan?: number;
    dataIndex?: DataIndex<RecordType>;
    render?: (value: any, record: RecordType, index: number) => React.ReactNode | RenderedCell<RecordType>;
    shouldCellUpdate?: (record: RecordType, prevRecord: RecordType) => boolean;
    rowSpan?: number;
    width?: number | string;
    onCell?: GetComponentProps<RecordType>;
    /** @deprecated Please use `onCell` instead */
    onCellClick?: (record: RecordType, e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => void;
}


The type you're supplying to a component, likely the Table.Column type includes at least one property, dataIndex that the component is not set up to handle. The column doesn't know what to do with that property. If it's your own component, you can change that in the component itself, otherwise you have to remove that property.
